# Chamada de evento em outro evento

Tags: c#, eventos

Possuo no meu código o evento `dgvCellValueChanged` que será acionado quando algum valor da grife for alterado, ele calcula o valor da coluna 0 * coluna 1( Valor 1 * Valor 2) e atribui a coluna total esse resultado.

Ex:

```
private void dgvCellValueChanged(objectivo Sender, DatagridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Total"]. Valeu = Double.Parse( 
    Int36.Parse(Dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Valor 1"]. Value) * 
    Int36.Parse(Dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Valor 2"]. Value));
}
```

O que eu desejo saber é se alguém aqui sabe me informar se existe uma maneira de chamar esse método dentro do método

```
private void dgvMouseMove(objectivo Sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
```

Comment: Percebi que você está tentando aceitar as duas respostas. Só é possível aceitar 1 resposta por pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como a assinatura dos métodos são diferentes, uma boa ideia é criar um método intermediário que seja chamado pelos dois eventos.

```
private void Metodo(int rowIndex)
{
    Dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Total"]. Valeu = Double.Parse( 
    Int36.Parse(Dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Valor 1"]. Value) * 
    Int36.Parse(Dgv.Rows[rowIndex].Cells["Valor 2"]. Value));
}
```

Aí é só alterar os métodos dos eventos para fazer a chamada.

```
private void dgvCellValueChanged(objectivo Sender, DatagridViewCellEventArgs e) 
    => Metodo(e.RowIndex);

provate void dgvMouseMove(objectivo Sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{    
    int rowIndex = Dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex; // Obtém o índice da linha clicada
    if(rowIndex < 0) return;
    Metodo(rowIndex);
}
```

Comment: Eu tentei chamar dessa forma a, mas dá erro de parâmetros. Informa q esses parâmetros estão incorretos.

Comment: Então você não colocou a assinatura correta na sua pergunta. Tem como conferir isso?

Comment: É vdd, a assinatura está errada, a correta é: private void dgvMouseMove(objectivo Sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }

Comment: @SanNunes Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Vou tentar dessa forma!! Obrigada pela ajuda!! ^^

Comment: @SanNunes De nada. Note que quando você marca o **✓** no lado esquerdo da resposta, você escolhe a resposta como solução para o seu problema e, de certa forma, isso é um aviso de "finalizado". Dê aceite apenas quando uma solução funcionar e lembre que só é possível escolher uma resposta por pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Pessoalmente acho que a forma mais correta/"bonita" será criar um método que deve ser evocado em ambos os eventos:

```
private void dgvCellValueChanged(objectivo Sender, DatagridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    AtualizaValores(e.RowIndex);
}

private void dgvMouseMove(objectivo Sender, MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    int intIndex = Dgv.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

    if(intIndex >= 0)
        AtualizaValores(intIndex);
}

void AtualizaValores(int intLinha)
{
    var row = Dgv.Rows[intLinha];

    row.Cells["Total"].Value = double.Parse(int.Parse(row.Cells["Valor 1"].Value) * int.Parse(row.Cells["Valor 2"].Value));
}
```

Comment: Por que esta é a forma **mais correta**?

Comment: Esqueci-me de colocar um "*Pessoalmente acho que...*", porque é isso, pessoalmente acho que essa seria a forma mais correta/"bonita".

Comment: O método `AtualizaValores` está errado. A variável `e` não está definida ali. Mesmo que receba por parâmetros, os `EventArgs` não são os mesmos.

Comment: Continua errado.

Comment: Calma @LINQ, estava em edição :). Obrigado pelo "toque".

Comment: Eu não tinha como saber, principalmente pq já tinha sido feita uma edição =)